# How to mock Firestore .collection in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I have following code in `Menu.js` And when I mocking it in test file I still have an error that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined` So far I tried with 2 mocks listed below, without success. I would like to have simple test for 2 scenarios, one with proper firestore response, and one with error. However I'm currently stuck on mocking firestore.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('menu').onSnapshot(
      { includeMetadataChanges: true },
      (snapshot) => snapshot
    )
    try {
      getCollection('menu').then((snapshot) => {
        const data = getData(snapshot)
        const menu = formatMenu(data)
        setAppetizers(menu.Appetizers)
        setDesserts(menu.Desserts)
        setSalads(menu.Salads)
        setMaindishes(menu.Mains)
        handleLoading(false)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      handleLoading(false)
      handleError(err)
      notify(DB_ERROR_MSG)
      console.log(error)
    }
  }, [])
```

Menu.test.js file with 2 failing mocks.

```js
jest.mock('../../firebase', () => {
  firebase: {
    db: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      ref: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      on: jest.fn((eventType, callback) => callback()),
      update: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
      remove: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
      once: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
      collection: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
    })
  }
})

jest.mock('../../firebase', () => {
  firebase: {
    db: {
      collection: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
    }
  }
})

test('Should render Menu component', () => {
  const { container } = renderWithRouter(<Menu />)
  const text = 'Menu'
  expect(container.innerHTML).toMatch(text)
})
```

Comment: Why you execute `jest.mock` twice? The second one should work

Comment: Sorry, I put 2 mocks to show, what I tried, unfortunatelly any of that mocks fails with `  TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`